# SonarQube in intellij not picking up unit test branch coverage when running analysis

Tags: unit-testing, intellij-idea, sonarqube

I’ve installed the SonarQube plugin in intellij and associated my project to our sonar server. The server tells me the branch coverage each class has and updates when I’ve submitted unit tests. However when I run a local analysis (right click on project –> analyze –> run inspection by name –> SonarQube), SonarQube tells me `X more branches need to be covered by unit tests to reach the minimum threshold of 65.0% branch coverage` for all of my classes and it doesn’t change locally even when I add more unit tests (but it does change on the server)

Any idea why this might be happening?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a known current limitation (that actually applies to both IntelliJ and Eclipse plugins): local analyses can't automatically execute unit tests, so they can't get the coverage results and give you the correct information.

The reason for this is that local analyses are just "standard" analyses that don't push data to the server. And by definition, SonarQube analyses don't execute any external tool, they just reuse previously generated reports if they need to.

If it's Maven-based project, you have a solution: just run `mvn clean org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:prepare-agent install -Dmaven.test.failure.ignore=true` prior to launching a local analysis. This should generate the coverage report at the default location and should therefore work.

Comment: Thanks, definitely good to know. I guess my follow up would be: how do you generate the reports prior to launching a local analysis and where would I put those reports?

Comment: Well, if it's Maven-based project, just run "mvn clean org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:prepare-agent install -Dmaven.test.failure.ignore=true" prior to launching a local analysis. This should generate the coverage report at the default location and should therefore work. But I've never tested it.

Comment: Awesome, that worked. Can you edit your answer to include that and I can accept it? :)

Comment: I was doing `mvn sonar:sonar` and was bugged about the threshold limit time after time. So when I found your answer to the question it got me on the right track. `mvn clean install sonar:sonar` solved it. A simple recompile :-)